# Can i use TransactionScope with my Ideablade EntityManager

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-entities

I am using DevForce Ideablade in my c# Winforms app. I have a series of inserts and updates that must all completely successfully or fail. I really don't want to do this as a stored procedure so I came across the TranscactionScope class.

Can i wrap my IdeaBlade calls to SaveChanges() with a TransactionScope object and throughout my code call SaveChanges and at the end call scope.Complete to sucessfully commit the transaction Basically like this.

```
try{
   using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
   {
       // process code
       entityManager.SaveChanges();

       // process code
       entityManager.SaveChanges();

       // process code
       entityManager.SaveChanges();

       scope.Complete;
   }
}
catch(TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yes that should work, have you tested it?

Comment: well at this point I wanted to ask if anyone had tried this or got an opinion as there is a lot of coding to do this and i need to convince my partner this should be done as c# code instead of a stored procedure. My main concern was that the ideablade framework would play nice with TransactionScope

Comment: It definitely works with EF, which I think DevForce is an extension of.